# How to make date input max attribute work in custom angular 1.5 component?

Tags: angularjs, html, typescript

I wrote this custom component:

```
<datetime value="vm.woComplete.CompleteDate" max="2016-10-25"></datetime>
```

**max** attribute doesnt work as it should in html5 validation date input.

**Why?**

```
// DateTimeComponent is used for date/time input with 2-way binding and UTC correction

namespace AppDomain {
    "use strict";

    class DateTimeController {

        value: Date;
        displayValue: Date;
        max: string;

        static $inject = ["$scope"];

        // West from UTC - TimezoneOffset is positive , East from UTC - TimezoneOffset is negative

        constructor($scope: ng.IScope) {
            $scope.$watch(
                "$ctrl.displayValue",
                (newValue: Date, oldValue: Date) => {
                    this.value = newValue;
                    var offset = this.displayValue.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;  // getTimezoneOffset returns minutes, we need hours
                    this.value.setHours(this.value.getHours() + offset); // LOCAL to UTC = UTC + Offset

                }
            );
        }

        $onInit() {
            this.displayValue = this.value;
            var offset = this.displayValue.getTimezoneOffset() / 60; // getTimezoneOffset returns minutes, we need hours
            this.displayValue.setHours(this.displayValue.getHours() - offset); // UTC to LOCAL = UTC - Offset
        }
    }

    const DateTimeComponent: ng.IComponentOptions = {

        //template: "<p><input type='date' class='form-control' ng-model='$ctrl.displayValue'></p><p><input type='time' class='form-control' ng-model='$ctrl.displayValue'></p>",
        template: "<p><input type='datetime-local' class='form-control' ng-model='$ctrl.displayValue' max='{{$ctrl.max}}'></p>",
        bindings: {
            value: "=",
            max: "@"
        },
        controller: DateTimeController

    };

    angular.module("app").component("datetime", DateTimeComponent);
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/iYt0sS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

1. *max* attribute for date input should be in format *yyyy-mm-dd*, so your component should be (max is set to October 28th for this example):

   ```
   <datetime value="app.dateTime" max="2016-10-28"></datetime>
   ```
2. `getHours()` function returns local (not universal like `getUTCHours()`), so you do not need to add and subtract offset hours, it is calculated by the JS Date object.
3. in your component you do not need a $watch and $init, just set *value*'s binding as `displayValue: '=value'`:

   ```
   namespace myApp {
     const dateTimeComponent = {
       templateUrl: 'app/datetime.component.html',
       bindings: {
         displayValue: '=value',
         max: '@'
       }
     };

     angular.module('app').component('datetime', dateTimeComponent);
   }
   ```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fFNY9C?p=preview

BTW, date type input has different behavior in different browsers, in some browsers (MAC Firfox, >IE10) calendar is not displayed at all. Styling and error messages are different, so, I would recommend you some third party widgets like bootstrap UI date picker - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker (probably along with time picker - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker)